# Java Http Post not working

Tags: java

I am making a Http post call from my java program, which is actually replicating the action of a html form.
 But always getting:

> {"RETURN_MESSAGE":"Invalid action.","RETURN_CODE":"-1","DATA":"ERROR"}

Source code:

```
String form_id = "237";
String module_list = "DSCHR";
String username = "Test Test";
String PUID = discharge_id + "|" + facility_id + "|"
        + "739739282898322" + "|" + "909283676222992";
String USER = "0" + "|" + security_id + "|" + "DSCHR" + "|" + "0";
String url = "callMe&PUID=" + PUID + "&USER=" + USER
        + "&username=" + username + "&form_id=" + form_id
        + "&module_list=" + module_list;

try {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "http://my-xyz-url/document?action="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(url));

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PUID", PUID));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("USER", USER));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("form_id", form_id));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("module_list", module_list));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters, "UTF-8"));

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the error trace?

Comment: no error trace is coming,,just  response {"RETURN_MESSAGE":"Invalid action.","RETURN_CODE":"-1","DATA":"ERROR"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check post URL once again as you are passing same form params as query params. And also populate correct request headers, if there's any.

Comment: variable URL in code contains same params as the request body params. I can see so clearly. Why are you passing values twice?